# getting an android phone detected by an NFC reader/writer (Basic NFC)

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, smartcard-reader, nfc-p2p

If I have an NFC reader/writer device, can I get it to detect my NFC enabled android phone, so that I may be able to transfer data from my phone to the device? I have found some links on Stackoverflow related to card emulation but they all say that card emulation is not possible or is too difficult

[How to make an android phone act as Contactless smart card?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800327/how-to-make-an-android-phone-act-as-contactless-smart-card)
[NFC card emulation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611810/nfc-card-emulation-android)
[Can an Android NFC phone act as an NFC tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6138077/can-an-android-nfc-phone-act-as-an-nfc-tag)
[NFC - p2p mode scenario](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785170/nfc-p2p-mode-scenario)
[NFC Peer2Peer Mode - Android Beam - ISO 18092](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14082178/nfc-peer2peer-mode-android-beam-iso-18092)
[Galaxy Nexus 4.1.1 and ISO14443 reader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11831651/galaxy-nexus-4-1-1-and-iso14443-reader)

But a pdf document I found online says

> Card emulation mode is based on ISO standards ISO 14443-A and ISO
>   14443-B, which are endorsed by the NFC Forum.

Moreover, it further says that P2P mode is also endorsed by the NFC forum, which, if I understood it correctly, is also like one phone working in reader emulation mode while the other working in card emulation mode

So if I have an NFC enabled phone, and USB reader/write, such as, say, [THIS ONE](http://www.bluetechnix.com/rainbow2006/site/495/Default.aspx), can I get it to detect my phone as an NFC device and transfer some data from my phone to the reader/writer?

---EDIT---
**Note**: I am not talking about getting the phone to work as a secure payment system or anything like that, my question is more basic: If I send out some data (say a string "ABC" or some number 1234) from my phone using NFC, can I get the external reader/writer to detect it?

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

An NFC device running in `P2P` mode can receive data from an Android phone using `Android Beam`.

The `NFC device` has to implement an `"NFC Forum Default SNEP Server"`, which is the equivalent of an `Android Beam receiverAndroid Beam receiver`.

There are various libraries and tools to do this, the one I can talk about is the `Python` based [NFCPy](http://nfcpy.org), it comes with a `beam.py` example program that does it out of the box.

Comment: Your provided link is dead.

Answer (score 0):

It didn't used to be possible at all without some awkward hacks however things have changed.

You can now [access the secure element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10494726/secure-element-access-control-on-ics-4-0-4/10506299#10506299) for example. If you want to have your emulate a Mifare card for example then you can use this I believe ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17220523/card-emulation-via-software-nfc)).

Or if you want it to emulate a more advanced card (such an NFC credit card) then try following the instructions [on this great blog](http://nelenkov.blogspot.nl/2012/10/emulating-pki-smart-card-with-cm91.html). This will require you to have a rooted phone and run [Cyanogenmod](http://www.cyanogenmod.org/).

I haven't tried the first method but the one which requires Cyanogenmod I've tested and written an application that allows my Nexus S to communicate with an [ACR122 reader](http://www.acs.com.hk/index.php?pid=product&id=ACR122U) and send arbitrary data.

Comment: Currently I cannot use any method that requires rooting the phone; I need to be able to do this using the android system that comes out of the box with the phone. One thing I still don't get though is, if a phone can act as a card writer, then it should be able to send out data easily. What is the difference between sending out data as a card writer, sending out data as a phone in P2P mode, and sending out data while acting as a card for an external card reader?

Comment: It can send out data easily, sending out data P2P is very limited by the Android software, not by the hardware and that's the problem, Android locks down a lot of the functionality. If the phone is acting as a MiFare card during emulation then cards are 'dumb', they can only responsd to data received, not send out information of their own accord.

Comment: so that means I cannot have the phone act as a card writer and send out data, which is then read by my external reader as the data read from a card?

Comment: where can I read more about limitations of P2P and what kind of functionality is locked down?

Comment: This was actually meant as a comment to this answer and not as a seperate answer to the original question: As an example, the ismb-snep-java (https://code.google.com/p/ismb-snep-java/) library enables communication between an ACR122U NFC reader and standard Android NFC devices.